# How can @QueryParam translate a parameter without value to boolean "false"?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'd like to use an URL like `http://www.example.com/rest/foo?bar` where the `bar` query parameter has no value and its presence alone should denote if a variable is `true` or `false`.

Currently the missing value is assumed to be `""` (empty) and passed to `new Boolean()` which treats it as `false`.

Is there a more elegant way of defining it than declaring the parameter to be String and converting it myself?

Like e.g. a class `javax.rs.BooleanFlag` or similar?

Comment: If you are deleting a resource, why don't you use the `DELETE` method?

Comment: In my case I was generate a statistic and sometimes it should delete the records that were used for this statistic afterwards. Please ignore the name of the parameter, it is irrelevant for my question and I edit it now! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
@GET
@Path("/some-path")
public Response myMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {

    boolean isParameterPresent = request.getParameterMap().contains("bar");

    ...
}
```

But the solutions shown in [peeskillet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260715/1426227) are the cleverest ways to achieve it.

Comment: That works, thanks. It's just a pity that the method signature now completely lacks information about this parameter. (Not that I'm a big friend of automatic WADL generation but sometimes it is nice...)

Answer (score 20):

I know it's an old question but I had the same trouble.

To solve my problem, I used the Annotation @DefaultValue :

```
@GET
@Path("/path")
public Response myMethod(@DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("foo") boolean foo) {
    if (foo) {
       ...
    }
}
```

So, when the request contains the parameter `foo` the boolean value will be false and if not it will be true. It shows the opposite of reality but if you're aware of it, it's quite simple to use.

Comment: The simpler and cleaner solution. I use it, for instance, for default pagination value (first=0;maxresult=50) in the web services

Answer (score 10):

**Note:** upon seeing [Phoste's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39766843/2587435), I'd go with his/her solution. I'm leaving this answer up, as there is still some useful information here.

> Is there a more elegant way of defining it than declaring the parameter to be String and converting it myself? Like e.g. a class `javax.rs.BooleanFlag` or similar?

No such type (`BooleanFlag`), If you look at the [javadoc for @QueryParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html), you'll see a list of options for how we can create a custom type to use a `@QueryParam` value (for the most part the same holds true for other `@XxxParam`s also)

> - Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
> - Have a `static` method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`)
> - Have a registered implementation of `ParamConverterProvider` JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a `ParamConverter` instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.

So from the first option, in theory, you should be able to do something like

```
public class Flag {

    private final boolean  isPresent;
    public Flag(String param) { isPresent = param != null; }
    public boolean isPresent() { return isPresent; }
}
```

```
@GET
public String get(@QueryParam("bar") Flag bar) {
    if (bar.isPresent()) {
        return "bar is present";
    } else {
        return "bar is not present";
    }
}
```

Now this works when the query flag is present. But when it's not, it acts like any other non-primitive type; it's null. So the call to `bar.isPresent` give an NPE. Tested with a `fromString` and `valueOf` with the same result. We *could* check `if (bar == null)`, but that's no better that just using a String and checking if the String is null. It's not *pretty*.

So the last option is the `ParamConverterProvider`. Which does actually work. Below is the implementation.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class FlagParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(
            Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (rawType != Flag.class) {
            return null;
        }

        return new ParamConverter<T>() {

            @Override
            public T fromString(String value) {
                return (T)new Flag(value);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(T value) { return null; } 
        };
    }  
}
```

Just make sure the provider is registered. It's a pretty clean solution in my opinion.

Comment: If I do not provide the `bar` parameter on my class, the `Flag` object is still `null`, so I still need to check for `bar == null ? false : bar.isPresent()`

Comment: Try this to get rid of the uncast check warning: `return rawType.cast(new Flag(value));`